# Why am I getting this weird output when creating a JAR file from commandline?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, command-line-arguments, executable-jar

I wrote a HelloWorld class in a folder "D:\Workspaces\Workspace\Packaging Programs into JAR Files\src". I am trying to create a Jar file containing this HelloWorld.class file, following [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html). So I opened cmd in the src directory and executed the following command.

```
jar cv HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld.class
```

I got this:

```
D:\Workspaces\Workspace\Packaging Programs i
nto JAR Files\src>jar cv HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld.class
HelloWorld.jar : no such file or directory
 δ╗£H                    ♦ META-INF/■╩  ♥     ☻       PK♥ δ╗£H            ¶   ME
K-*╬╠╧│R0╘3ασr.JM,IM╤u¬♦        ÿδ↓─¢[*h°↨%&τñ*8τ↨§Σ↨%û òk≥r±r☺ P╖îqëC   D   PK♥
 c╖£H            ►   HelloWorld.classmPMK├@►}█|515╡╡⌡│P☼B¶1Å§/éx(*D⌠α)iù▓%╔JL¶⌂û
▲¶<°♥ⁿQΓl¶é╨à▌Ö}≤▐╠█²·■°♦päü♥‼₧ì6VÜΦ8Φb╒B╧Bƒ┴<▬Ö(N↑4⌂∩åA?òS╬αìE╞/╩4µ∙u¶'äΦi$2å╛⌂
7₧GÅQÉD┘ï\d│æ↕:í,≤      ?‼è∞¥≤$æ╖2Oªçèφ┬B╙┬Üïul0┤¬≥┴≡I◄v,l║╪┬6⌡¿e♀φz╠e<τôΓ▼¶>?¶<
┌d∟♀6e♥èîó▒*♫÷B ↓ª╙¼@EYé√G▌%⌐BφW4:┌←⌠ÜεT]5Ω¬‼╥¬ª,* P♥   èY!☺  ⌐☺  PK δ╗£H    ☻
         ♦               META-INF/■╩  PK☺☻¶ δ╗£H╖îqëC   D   ¶             =   ME
TA-INF/MANIFEST.MFPK☺☻¶ c╖£H♥   èY!☺  ⌐☺  ►             ┬   HelloWorld.classPK♣♠
    ♥ ♥ ╗   !☻
D:\Workspaces\Workspace\Packaging Programs i
nto JAR Files\src>
```

Why is this happening? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: It should be `jar cf`, not `jar cv`.

Comment: @BethanyLouise But from the doc I linked to in the question, "The f option indicates that you want the output to go to a file rather than to stdout." - But what if I don't care about the file and do want the output to go to the output stream?? I am learning and wanted to try each option separately, so that I understand it well.

Comment: Why would you want to output your JAR archive to system out?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the thing. How _can_ a JAR file go to `stdout`? I was doing this to check exactly that as well, because they said so. "...output to go to a file rather than to stdout." - which means the output _could_ go to `stdout`.

Comment: The file that f makes it write to is the jar. By typing `jar cv` instead of `jar cf`, you told it to output the contents of the jar through Command Prompt instead of writing it to a file. Since it isn't meant to be displayed in plaintext, you got, well, that jumbled mess of characters when you told the computer to display it that way.

Comment: @BethanyLouise Oh I understand it now. Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: The JAR command line tool was intended (I believe) for creating JAR files.  If you want to pipe a JAR file to some other output stream, it is fairly easy to do that from a Java program.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually the tutorial mentioned `stdout`, which put the question in my mind and I tried it to see how this kind of thing works. I don't know how this could ever be useful or if this is ever used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `-f` parameter which tells the JAR tool to output to a file rather than the console:

```
jar cvf HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld.class
```

**Update:**

You could achieve the same result as above *without* the `-f` flag by telling JAR to send the output to the standard output, and then redirecting into the actual JAR file you want.  Hence, the following would accomplish the same as above:

```
jar cv HelloWorld.class > HelloWorld.jar
```

It should be noted that piping the output from JAR into an output file is a feature of the OS and not a feature of Java.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But from the doc I linked to in the question, "The f option indicates that you want the output to go to a file rather than to stdout." - But what if I don't care about the file and do want the output to go to the output stream?? I am learning and wanted to try each option separately, so that I understand it well.